# Multiple Formats: Reading Working Routine From File

Tags: c++, stream

It is my job to store the workout routine for a given individual in a `multimap<string, Exercise*>` using an overloaded extraction operator in main. I wanted to know if my code for said operator can be simplified and made more intuitive. There are three classes, but I have only shown `Routines`; the others seem trivial to include. Implementations will be done in the header file. I will be extracting information from the following file (routine.txt):

```
Donald Duck,2
Chin-ups,30
Lat Pulldown,20,90
David Ash, 2
Push-ups,5
Wrist curl,10, 2
```

The format is `name,numberOfExercises` followed by numberOfExcercises exercises. Each exercise involves weights or does not. A weighted exercise is formatted as `exerName,reps,weight`. A non-weighted exercise is formatted as `exerName,reps`. The inclusion of a space after a comma is not a mistake. main contains the following:

```
int main() {
   Routines routines;
   string name;
   ifstream inf("routines.csv");

   inf >> routines;
}
```

The routines class has the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include "exercise.h"
#include "weightedexercise.h"

using namespace std;

class Routines
{
  multimap<string, Exercise*> routineMap;

public:
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Routines& rout)
  {
    string name, line;
    char comma;
    int numEx, rep, weight = 0;
    // numEx is number of exercises.
    // name is name of person. line is the exercise information.

    getline(is, name, ',');

    do
    {
      is >> numEx;
      getline(is, line);

      for(int i = 0; i < numEx; i++)
      {
        getline(is, line, ',');
        is >> rep;
        is.get(comma);
        if(comma == ',')
          is >> weight;

        if(weight)
        {
          rout.routineMap.insert(multimap<string,
          Exercise *>::value_type(name, new WeightedExercise(line, rep, weight)));
          getline(is, line);
        }
        else
        {
          rout.routineMap.insert(multimap<string,
          Exercise *>::value_type(name, new Exercise(line, rep)));
        }

        weight = 0;
      }
    } while(getline(is, name, ','));
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't see any `delete` commands!. I think your problem will simply be solved be changing `Exercise*` into `Exercise` as the value type for your map.

Answer (score 1):

#### Avoid pointers

In this case, there seems to be no particularly good reason for your `map` to store pointers to the data instead of just storing the data directly. It'll simplify your code a bit if you just have it store something like a `vector<exercise>`. Alternatively, you could consider using a `std::multimap<std::string, Exercise>` (which has a similar effect).

Note that many people are likely to give advice more like: "avoid raw pointers". While that's good advice in itself, I prefer to avoid (explicit use of) pointers entirely if possible. If you find that you *can't* avoid using a pointer, then use a smart pointer. But if you can avoid using any sort of pointer at all, so much the better.

#### Distribution of responsibilities

You've defined an `Exercise` class (or struct), but all the responsibility for reading an Exercise from a file has been assigned to `Routines`. At least IMO, it would be better if an `Exercise` knew how to extract itself from a file, and a `Routine` just made use of that to read the exercises in a routine.

#### `map` data type

Right now, your `Routines` is basically just a `map` with an overload of `operator>>` to extract data and populate that map from the file. We don't need to define a new class just for that purpose though. `map` already uses a template to define the type of data it stores--we can just use that (and give it a name, if we like):

```
using routine = std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Exercise> >;
```

Putting those together we get extraction operators for `routine` and `exercise` that look something like this:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Exercise &e) {
    std::string temp;
    std::getline(in, temp);
    std::istringstream is(temp);
    std::getline(is, e.name, ',');
    is >> e.reps;
    if (is.peek() == ',') {
        is.ignore(1);
        is >> e.weight;
    }
    else
        e.weight = 0;
    return in;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, routine &r) {
    std::getline(is, r.first, ',');
    int count;
    is >> count;
    is.ignore(1024, '\n');
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        exercise e;
        is >> e;
        r.second.push_back(e);
    }
    return is;
}
```

So now we've restricted the messiness of reading an `exercise` correctly to a somewhat smaller area. A `Routine` just reads a name and a some number of `Exercise`s.

With those in place, initializing a map of routines from a file can look something like this:

```
std::ifstream in("routines.csv");

std::map<std::string, std::vector<exercise>> routines {
    std::istream_iterator<routine>(in), {} };
```

Of course, if you *really* want to define your own complete class for `Routine`, you can do that--but I'd still keep the responsibility for reading an `Exercise` in an extractor specifically for an `Exercise`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid owning raw pointers. Even without exceptions, they are prone to leak.
   Use a sensible [`std::unique_ptr`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::any`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`std::variant`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). The latter even avoid extra dynamic allocations, though at the cost of potentially wasting a small amount of memory.
2. Are you sure there's always at least one person?